# Most elegant way to achieve this one-column CSS layout with multiple backgrounds

Tags: layout, css, background

What is the most simple and elegant way to achieve the following one-column layout using CSS2.1/CSS3, so it will look identical in Firefox/Chrome/Opera?

I have a yellow background consisting of 3 images (header.png, repeating middle.png and footer.png) and a red paragraph of text (variable height). I want the text to partially cover the header and footer image (as on the illustration below). The background outside yellow box should be transparent.

[image: example]

One solution is to have one big  with mutliple backgrounds and padding:

```
<div style="background: url(header.png) no-repeat center top, url(footer.png) no-repeat center bottom; padding: 50px;">
    <p>A lot of text...</p>
</div>
```

But then what about the middle background? If I add it to multiple backgrounds with repeat-y, it will be visible under transparent parts of header.png and footer.png.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: tried border images? EDIT: nope... nvm... not in FF yet... at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use pseudo elements! IMO the most elegant way to implement something like this -- and fairly well supported too

i made a quick jsfiddle outlining my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/vfdFR/6/

Your images aren't showing but it should work well -- apply the repeating background to the div element and the header and footer images to the div:before and div:after respectively and with a bit of z-index everything should be looking right

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The more compatible but more hacky method is to use 4 `<div>`s. One `<div>` contains the paragraph of text. (OK, so this could be a `<p>`, whatever.) It is contained within the middle of the outer three `<div>`s, each of which have one part of the background. Negative margins on the text (and possibly z-index on the middle `<div>`) then allow it to overlap the top and bottom images.

The less hacky but less compatible method is to use one outer `<div>` and a [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/border-image) that draws the background. You will still need negative margins on the text to extend into the top and bottom parts of the border.

Comment: Neither method is elegant! The latter is not widely supported.
As to 4 divs, when I set a negative margin-top on the inside `<div>` with text, it cuts my header background and I need to play with `position: relative`. Come on, aren't there easy ways for this simple layout?? It's so common!

Comment: @niutech If it was that simple then you would have solved it already.